# Yii2 Can we change the assets directory location?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Yii2 automatically generates the assets in web folder. How can we change it to any other folder?

For example. If I create a folder named `myassets` in web folder. It is possible to store all the assets in this folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change it by editing [$basePath](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$basePath-detail) of [AssetManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html).

Through application config:

```
'assetManager' => [
    'basePath' => '@webroot/my-assets',
],
```

Through application component:

```
\Yii:$app->assetManager->basePath = '@webroot/my-assets';
```